# xPath: Can you select only nodes with a certain number of a specific child node?

Tags: xpath, numbers, nodes, children

I want to select nodes [Stufe0/Stufe1/Stufe2] that contain more than 2 specific nodes[nr].
Is that even possible with xPath?
This should be found:

```
<Stufe1 id="RI006-004_A00000006" typ="person">
          <Inhalt>Marienstift Dekan und Kapitel <Regestennummer>
              <nr source_type="D" type="nennung">27</nr>, <nr source_type="D" type="nennung">55</nr>, <nr source_type="D" type="nennung">360</nr>
            </Regestennummer>
          </Inhalt>
        </Stufe1>
```

This shouldn't be found:

```
<Stufe1 id="RI006-004_A00000007" typ="person">
          <Inhalt>Marienstift Vögte <Regestennummer>
              <nr source_type="D" type="nennung">360</nr>
            </Regestennummer>
          </Inhalt>
        </Stufe1>
```

Please note: I am a beginner to xPath and this is my first question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Stufe1[Inhalt/Regestennummer/count(nr) > 1]
```

Please remove those commas in between elements.

Comment: That solution is fine for XPath 2.0. In 1.0 it has to be `//Stufe1[count(Inhalt/Regestennummer/nr) > 1]`